# how many bidirectional lstm layers to use and how many is too many? Any advice on very imbalanced dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Would much appreciate your help.
I am new to the RNN and I am trying to implement a RNN architecture to classify protein sequences. essentially they are one hot encoded np arrays. 
I have an issue that the data is very imbalanced:
Examples:
    Total: 34909
    Positive: 282 (0.81% of total)

Therefore I am planning to implement the weights for the different classes by adding the class_weight=class_weight parameter when model is fitted.

I am also planning to use the f1 on the validation as a metric instead of accuracy or loss for the model as I am not interested in the true negatives.

Moreover, I am planning to implement transfer learning as I have dataseets with more positive data and datasets with only few points therefore I am planning to pretrain a general model and use the weights to further train on the specific problem.

I have come up with this architecture of the model however I am not sure if adding 4 bidirectional LSTM layers is a wise choice?:

```
from keras import regularizers

if output_bias is not None:
    output_bias = Constant(output_bias)
model = Sequential()
# First LSTM layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1), input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Second LSTM layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Third LSTM layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Forth LSTM layer
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#First Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(units=128,kernel_initializer='he_normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Adding the output layer
if output_bias == None:
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
else:
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid',
                    bias_initializer=output_bias,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), loss=BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=metrics)
model.build()
```

How do I know how many LSTM layers I should add? is it just trial and error?
Is there anything else I should include in the layers?
model.summary():

```
    Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bidirectional_13 (Bidirectio (None, 5, 100)            28400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_14 (Bidirectio (None, 5, 100)            60400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_15 (Bidirectio (None, 5, 100)            60400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 5, 100)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_16 (Bidirectio (None, 100)               60400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 128)               12928     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 222,657
Trainable params: 222,657
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

I have built this model by going through multiple tutorials such as https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn
and https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data

Would appreciate if you could point in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: use a validation set to check overfitting, use high dropout and if the training and validation metrics are consistent then you can keep as many LSTM layers as you want, but they are slow to train remember that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zabir. I am actually getting an error with this model do you know whats happening? tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_8_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[node dense_8_target (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3007) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_39270]